# jQuery data table check if there is data

Tags: jquery

I have a data table. I want to see if it's full, then destroy it.

The problem is it does not recognize `any()`, or `fnSettings()`. Is there any jQuery way to check if my table has any data?

```
var table= $('#example').DataTable();
debugger;
if(!table.data().any()) {
  alert('Empty table');
}
```

Unfortunately when it reaches the line which has `any()`, I get an error that says it does not recognize `any()`.

Comment: Maybe use something like that: ` if (table.data() && !table.data.any()) {... }` ?

Comment: I tried,again the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.count()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/count()):

```
if(!table.data().count()){
    alert("Empty table");
}
```

Comment: avaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'count'

Comment: yes otherwise I would get error for this line also  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

Comment: Sometimes you load it twice or two different versions. Check if your js is in order, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used toSource() jquery method to check, whether the selected element has data or not. I don't think its an appropriate way, hope it works. with toSource() method you can inspect the object in jquery.

```
var table= $('#example').DataTable();
debugger;
if(table.data().toSource() == '({})') {
  alert('Empty table');
}
```

Comment: avaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'roSource'

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();

            if (table.data().count()) {
                alert("there is data");

            }
            else {
                alert("empty");
            }
```